# How to append dataframe values to empty lists based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, loops, append

I have the following dataframe:

```
dictionary = {'Monday': {'John': 5,
                  'Lisa': 1,
                  'Karyn': 'NaN',
                  'steve': 1,
                  'ryan': 4,
                  'chris': 5,
                  'jessie': 6},
         'Friday': {'John': 0,
                  'Lisa': 1,
                  'Karyn':'NaN',
                  'steve': 4,
                  'ryan': 7,
                  'chris': 'NaN',
                   'jessie': 11},
        'Saturday': {'John': 0,
                  'Lisa': 1,
                  'Karyn': 2,
                  'steve': 4,
                   'ryan': 'NaN',
                   'chris': 'NaN',
                   'jessie': 1}}
                     
tab = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
```

```
      Monday    Friday  Saturday
John    5          0    0
Lisa    1          1    1
Karyn   NaN       NaN   2
steve   1          4    4
ryan    4          7    NaN
chris   5        NaN    NaN
jessie  6         11    1
```

I have these empty lists

```
mon_only = []
fri_only = []
sat_only = []
mon_fri_only = []
mon_sat_only = []
fri_sat_only = []
mon_fri_sat = []
```

I would like to append the index to these lists based on where the fall. For example if an index name has a value greater than zero then its considered present in that column. If its present in only one Monday column then its go to the mon_only list. If its present in all three columns then it'll go in the mon_fri_sat list.

The results should essentially look like this

```
mon_only = ['John','chris']
fri_only = []
sat_only = ['Karyn']
mon_fri_only = ['ryan']
mon_sat_only = []
fri_sat_only = []
mon_fri_sat = ['Lisa','steve','jessie']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to first create the combinations, then using a condition and `df.dot` , get column names where value is not `'NaN'` or `0`. Finally reindex and fill nan with `[]`

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import defaultdict
```

---

```
delim = ","
c = ~(tab.eq("NaN")|tab.eq(0))
d = c.dot(c.columns+delim).str.rstrip(delim)

ind = [delim.join(idx) for i in range(1,len(tab.columns)+1) 
       for idx in list(combinations(tab.columns,i))]
defd = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in d.items():
    if v not in defd[v]:
        defd[v].append(k)
    
out_d = pd.Series(defd).reindex(ind,fill_value=[]).to_dict()
```

---

Output:

```
print(out_d)

{'Monday': ['John', 'chris'],
 'Friday': [],
 'Saturday': ['Karyn'],
 'Monday,Friday': ['ryan'],
 'Monday,Saturday': [],
 'Friday,Saturday': [],
 'Monday,Friday,Saturday': ['Lisa', 'steve', 'jessie']}
```

---

Save this dictionary in a variable and slice by keys to get to your desired output.

---

**If combinations doesnot matter, then same code but smaller:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
defd = defaultdict(list)
c = ~(tab.eq("NaN")|tab.eq(0))
d = c.dot(c.columns+',').str.rstrip(",")
for k,v in d.items():
    if v not in defd[v]:
        defd[v].append(k)
```

---

```
print(defd)
defaultdict(list,
            {'Monday': ['John', 'chris'],
             'Monday,Friday,Saturday': ['Lisa', 'steve', 'jessie'],
             'Saturday': ['Karyn'],
             'Monday,Friday': ['ryan']})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've never heard of these functions before. I'll go read up on this and keep practicing.

Comment: @newbzzs Glad I could help. Just a note, replace `tab.eq("NaN")` in the code with `tab.isna()` if the values are actually `np.nan` and not a string `'NaN'` as it is in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
dictionary = {'Monday': {'John': 5,
                  'Lisa': 1,
                  'Karyn': 'NaN',
                  'steve': 1,
                  'ryan': 4,
                  'chris': 5,
                  'jessie': 6},
         'Friday': {'John': 0,
                  'Lisa': 1,
                  'Karyn':'NaN',
                  'steve': 4,
                  'ryan': 7,
                  'chris': 'NaN',
                   'jessie': 11},
        'Saturday': {'John': 0,
                  'Lisa': 1,
                  'Karyn': 2,
                  'steve': 4,
                   'ryan': 'NaN',
                   'chris': 'NaN',
                   'jessie': 1}}
                     
tab = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
tab.replace('NaN', np.nan, inplace=True)
tab['Name']=tab.index

days=['Monday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

for d in days:
    tab[d+'_bool']=~tab[d].isin([0, np.nan])
    
tab.groupby([d+'_bool' for d in days])['Name'].apply(list)
```

Output:

```
Monday_bool  Friday_bool  Saturday_bool
False        False        True                           [Karyn]
True         False        False                    [John, chris]
             True         False                           [ryan]
                          True             [Lisa, steve, jessie]
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to respond. Much appreciated